# Get split number and string from string

Tags: javascript, regex

I have an array of string like below:

```
var array =[];
array.push("Complex12");
array.push("NumberCar1");
array.push("Protect5");
```

I want to split the string and number of each item.

```
   var Id = parseInt(array[0].match(/\d/g));
   var type = array[0].replace(/\d+/g, '');
```

But I only get Id = 1(I want 12) and type = "Complex", where am I wrong?
thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you just missed `+` in first regexp

```
var Id = parseInt(array[0].match(/\d+/g));
```

Answer (score 0):

Do it in one pattern with capture groups:

```
var mystr = "Complex12";

if (m = mystr.match(/^([a-z]+)([0-9]+)$/i)) {
    var type = m[1];
    var id = m[2];
}
```