# Javascript convert string to array with seperate letters and number

Tags: javascript, arrays, string, split

I have a string where I need to strip out the letters and the numbers.  There will only be one number in the string.

So for example this string:

`"AM12"` I would like to split into this:

`['A','M',12]`

What is the most efficient way to do this?  I was able to do it before with dashes in the string separating them (A-M-12) but was asked to remove the dashes.

Here is code I used for with dashes:
`let arrUrl = myString.split('-');`

Thanks.

Comment: Is anything else consistent about the string? always 2 letters for example? or letters are always first? Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25028217/get-split-number-and-string-from-string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `/\d+|./`. It will match consecutive numbers or individual characters.

```js
const split = str => str.match(/\d+|./g)

console.log(split("AM12"))
console.log(split("Catch22"))
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need the number portion to be numeric in your resulting array, you could try something like this

```js
let test = 'AM12'
let res = []
let num = ''
test.split('').forEach(e=>isNaN(e)?res.push(e):num+=e)
res.push(parseInt(num))
console.log(res)
```

Comment: FYI: `isNaN(" ")` is false. So, `AM 12` will also return `["A", "M", 12]`

Answer (score 0):

You can scan the input string linearly, char by char, and keep track of any running number, also you should pay attention to the negative numbers.

The following snippet handles negative numbers and also multiple numbers in the same input.

```js
function isDigit(char) {
  return char >= "0" && char <= "9";
}

function split(input) {
  const result = [];

  // keep track of the running number if any
  let runningNum = 0;
  let isNum = false;
  let isNegative = false;

  for (let i = 0; i < input.length; i++) {
    const ch = input[i];

    if (isDigit(ch)) {
      // check for negative value
      if (i > 0 && input[i - 1] === "-") {
        isNegative = true;
      }

      runningNum *= 10;
      runningNum += (isNegative ? -1 : 1) * (ch - "0");
      isNum = true;
    } else {
      // push previous running number if any
      if (isNum) {
        result.push(runningNum);
        runningNum = 0; // reset
        isNum = false;
        isNegative = false;
      }

      // if current char is a "-" sign and the following char is a digit continue,
      // if not then it's a hyphen
      const isLastChar = i === input.length - 1;
      if (!isLastChar && input[i] === "-" && isDigit(input[i + 1])) {
        continue;
      }

      result.push(ch);
    }
  }

  // in case the number at the end of the input string
  if (isNum) {
    result.push(runningNum);
  }

  return result;
}

const inputs = ["AM-12", "AM-12-30", "AM-12B30", "30", "a3b", "ab", "-", "-abc", "a-12-"];
for (let input of inputs) {
  console.log(`"${input}": `, split(input));
}
```